# Is it possible to create/encode variable frame rate video files with Microsoft Windows Media Foundation?

Tags: ms-media-foundation

I have successfully created an application that puts JPEG files into a MKV (Matroska) container where each frame can have a different duration. These files (Example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kVfMqr8CpwxOSSjNojPlzFVJWuu5MoNv/view?usp=sharing) play correctly in VLC, FFMPEG and Windows Media Player.

I successfully converted this file using FFMPEG to a MJPEG video stream in a MP4 container, the frame count and timing was preserved. Is it theoretically possible to do the same file conversion using the Media Foundation API in Windows 10, or even better, compress the video stream as H.264 while preserving the frame count and timing?

My first experiments trying to create VFR videos (H.264 in MP4) with Media Foundation [IMFSinkWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/sink-writer) failed because the files would end up as being constant frame rate with my source frames being duplicated a lot (if the output video file frame rate is higher than the input frame rate). Now I wonder if I should invest the time to rewrite it using [IMFMediaSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfidl/nn-mfidl-imfmediasession) instead.